# Se puede guardar una vista en una variable en codeigniter 3?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, vistas, model-view-controller

Necesito guardar una vista en una variable para crear templates de correos electronicos, quisera guardar la vista en una varable ejemplo

```
$html=$this->load->view("templates/email/reset");
```

Para despues utilizarlo en otra funcion

```
$this->email->set("example@example.com",$html);
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta era muy sencilla solo es agregandole el parametro TRUE al la funcion que ejecuta la impresion de la vista.

```
$html=$this->load->view("templates/email/reset",$parametros,TRUE);
$this->email->set("example@example.com",$html);
```

De esta manera encontre la solucion a este problema.